# How to alter/remove this function's output without modifying the original theme files?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a theme framework and am trying very hard to resist the temptation of editing core files. I want to add the functionality of post formats, but I need to be able to remove certain elements for specific post formats.

```
            function thesis_teaser_headline($post_count, $post_image) {
                thesis_hook_before_teaser_headline($post_count); #hook

                if ($post_image['show'] && $post_image['y'] == 'before-headline')
                    echo $post_image['output'];

                echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent link to ' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>\n";

                if ($post_image['show'] && $post_image['y'] == 'after-headline')
                    echo $post_image['output'];

                thesis_hook_after_teaser_headline($post_count); #hook
            }
```

What would be the most efficient way to go about removing headline data for a post format such as 'link' (for example)? This function is being called to generate the content for the teasers from the homepage loop. I could just make an entire custom loop, but it won't tie in with the Thesis backend which makes it much less flexible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Thesis, but I see it is calling hooks, so you could possibly put one of your functions on these, that in case you don't want any content from original `thesis_teaser_headline()` would turn on output buffering (`ob_start()`) on `before` hook, and clean it (`ob_end_clean()` or `$content = ob_get_clean()` if you want to alter its content, not completely replace) on `after` hook.

Comment: It seems to only work if I add it directly into the core code. Using the hook to add it before and after, I get a wrong parameter count for  ob_end_clean. It seems like a great solution but either I'm doing it wrong or it isn't playing well with hooks.

Comment: Well, Obviously you shouldn't add `ob_*` directly to hooks, but your own function that will handle hooks. And call ob_start/ob_get_clean if necessary.

Comment: Hah! Sorry, I've never worked with ob_* before and had no idea what I was doing. It does indeed work perfectly now. In your opinion, would using ob_* to hide the headline area of posts under certain conditions be bad practice? I still have the option of rewriting the theme's output functions but that will be ~200 extra lines of code.

Comment: Well that highly depends on many circumstances, I can't give any certain answer here. Although usually if it does improve the code, gives more flexibility compared to current state and you have time for it - I'd say yes, rewrite. Again, you can always find a way to improve something that already exists, that's an infinite loop. So you must consider if you really **need** that. :) Hope my opinion helps you find own way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/* */` control to make the function in comment. So it will not be executed. Or put just the section you want to delete between them...

Comment: Commenting is something I really want to avoid as there's about 7-8 of these functions that comprise the "building" process of the teaser content and I will need them on some post formats and not others (i.e., the "link" format doesn't need a post image or headline but the "gallery" format will). Also, I'm looking for something I can use on sites I build for other people that they can upgrade without being trolled. Hopefully there's another solution somewhere, but it's always a final option.

Comment: @Alice I understand. But can you explain a little bit more what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What about tweaking the html with jquery? Check on the post classes (the list of css classes that's on the div that wraps each post) to see if you can select what you need from there. 
On top of all, I recommend to avoid using that framework, it's pure nightmare when you need to tweak it.